# failed to load csv data

Tags: mysql

This script

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cmx_siusd_m1;
CREATE TABLE cmx_siusd_m1(trade_date DATETIME, si_open DECIMAL(8,5), si_high DECIMAL(8,5), si_low DECIMAL(8,5), si_close DECIMAL(8,5), si_ticks INT, 

si_oi INT, PRIMARY KEY(trade_date));

LOAD DATA INFILE 'D:/datafolder/cmx_siusd_m1.csv' IGNORE INTO TABLE cmx_siusd_m1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
IGNORE 1 LINES (@trade_date, si_open, si_high, si_low, si_close, si_ticks, si_oi)
SET trade_date = STR_TO_DATE(@trade_date, '%Y.%m.%d %H:%i');
```

can't read this data

```
2009.04.17 13:45,11.95000,11.97000,11.94000,11.96000,41,0  
2009.04.17 13:46,11.95000,11.97000,11.94000,11.95000,34,0  
2009.04.17 13:47,11.96000,11.97000,11.94000,11.96000,32,0  
2009.04.17 13:48,11.95000,11.97000,11.93000,11.96000,39,0  
2009.04.17 13:49,11.97000,11.98000,11.94000,11.97000,42,0  
2009.04.17 13:50,11.95000,11.98000,11.95000,11.97000,32,0  
2009.04.17 13:51,11.96000,11.98000,11.96000,11.96000,34,0
```

I get the errors incorrect decimal value, incorrect integer value, and incorrect datetime value for each of the column tables in mysql.

Comment: ... done, sorry I had over looked this :-)

Comment: What character(s) terminate the lines in your CSV?  MySQL defaults to `\n`, but files generated by Windows usually use `\r\n`.  You may need to add `LINES TERMINATED BY` clause.

Comment: I just added this `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'` but no rows where inserted. (& I got no errors)

Comment: @Harry yes you are correct ... but if we hadn't got any write answer and find it later then we have to post outself so that next person who got same problem could get hint to solve it...

Comment: Weird. It should work. Maybe add `ENCLOSED BY ''` (enclosed by nothing, its empty by default, but... im out of ideas).

Comment: I dont like this trade_date as primary key. What if there are duplicates?

Comment: Interesting. It works here on v5.5.28, just as described. What verson are you using?

Comment: Guys thanks 4 all the help, my version is 5.5.25; @Kamil I do not think there are any duplicates in the pk column. Besides \r and \n how else can I terminate lines?

Comment: `\n` under linux (mysql default, Linux) and `\r\n` (Microsoft style). More here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline Try to copy content and paste into windows notepad (create new file). Then set termination to `\r\n` and see what happends.

Comment: @Kamil hey thanks. Your suggestion worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussion in comments - your problem is format of your text file. After trying `\r\n` and `\n` line termination we tried to create new file, with windows format and it worked.

So problem is weird file format, with unknown line termination. If you need to use that file format (it comes from something and you dont want to re-write new file each import) - you can open that file in hexeditor and see what character codes are at the end of line.

Maybe this is `\n\r` (not `\r\n`).

Comment: Yeah it could be the swapping of the line terminations... am yet to try that and see; but I thought I would also share that when I copied the data to a new csv file, the file size actually halved! So yeah it was some weird format